# Session not working in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am new to ASP.Net and I can't seem grasp the working of my session. In some situations it works and in others not. Here you see the code where I create the session in one webform and call it in another form. In the Form_Load the second form can get data from the session but in the button_click event (page reload) the Session is "null". Can somebody help me?

code Form 1:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["data"] = TextBox.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/RapportFormulier2.aspx", false);
}
```

code Form 2:

```
string s;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Logic logic = new Logic();
        logic.login(credentials);
        s = (string)(Session["data"]); // data is stored in the variable s
    }
}

protected void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    string test = s; //null (normally because the reload)
    string s2 = (string)(Session["data"]); //null idk why
}
```

I put the connection to my logic class in my postback since i have to re initiase it anyway.

I am also open to some tips, since it is obvious i am struggling in ways.

edit: I tried storing the first s in another session but even that i couldn't get back in the button_click...

Form 2 load:

```
Session["data2"] = s;
```

Form 2 button_click:

```
string s2 = (string)(Session["data2"]); // null
```

Comment: The Webpage RapportFormulier2.aspx is your Form 2?

Comment: Do not use fields in your page classes. They do not persist through postbacks. After a response is finished, that instance of your page is discarded, including all its state. The next postback will be an entirely new instance of the page.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ It indeed is, i changed some stuf around in my code to make it more viewer friendly.

Comment: @mason I understand that but i just wanted to show a contrast that the same happend to my session, which i don't understand.

Comment: But this works fine for me. Probably you've missed something here because I get the `Session`'s value successfully in this line: `string s2 = (string)(Session["data"]); `

Comment: Do you have anywhere else where your session is cleared or the values are removed?

Comment: @S.Akbari hmm, let me look at my code again then

Comment: @S.Akbari It doesn't work for me, I am prob. blind doh.

Comment: Please test this: `Session["data"] = TextBox.Text; string s2 = (string)(Session["data"]);`. If s2 has value here?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi This indeed works.

Comment: I tried something and now i am even more confused why it doesn't work (c edits)...

Comment: Write this: `s = (string)(Session["data"]);` out of `if (!IsPostBack)` . now put break points on both events. When you click on button before button click you can see the session in form_load event and better understand when it changes to null.

Comment: Are you starting at Form 1 then clicking a button to show Form 2 every time?  Or are you stopping Visual Studio running at any point in time - and loading Form 2 directly?

Comment: @Andez I a starting from Form1 where i click a button that redirects to Form2 i do not close my VSat any time

Comment: can you show your  webconfig file

Comment: @Usman I did some stuf and i think i am getting wiser, i am going to repost my question with more information.

Comment: Any luck?  Just had a quick google tonight and found this.  [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_)

Comment: Well the thing is that my webservice overwrites my sessions for some reason, this didn't happen in php, but it does happen in asp.net. I am planning to use cookieholder or something, but haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the way you took the project

If you are sure that the code you wrote is correct, you can **delete** or comment this line from the web.config file. (Under `<system.web>`)

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />
```