# Setting up session value as the session value comes empty

Tags: session, asp-classic

Physical Path:

```
{..\Dev\Source\Web\Clients\Property\mainmenu.asp}
{..\Map-Dev\Source\Web\Map\index.asp}
```

Virtual Path:

```
{..\Property\mainmenu.asp}
{..\Property\Map\index.asp}
```

URL:

```
{http://localhost:10001/mainmenu.asp}
{http://localhost:10001/Map/index.asp}
```

Not getting session value in `index.asp`, always comes empty. Should I need to set session value in `mainmenu.asp` when I am opening the `index.asp`?

But when I am passing session value through query string it comes properly in the `index.asp`. But it does not sense dynamically when main application session expires. Should I need to do anything else.

Please advise.

Map folder is hosted as a separate application in IIS under Property...the main application

Comment: If you have the two set up as separate applications then I think that might be the problem - sharing sessions between classic asp applications is problematic. You might be better creating your own session state system with a DB or cookies?

Comment: You posting about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58786186/692942)?

Comment: @Ralpharama it’s the same local web application, if it’s not sharing the Session variables it’s because there are separate applications inside that are using a different application pool. Session state by default with a Classic ASP Web Application uses in memory sessions, which means for the session to be shared both have to use the same application pool.

Comment: See answers to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509573/session-not-working-in-asp-net